# Reading multiple string lines, c++ to multiple variables;

Tags: c++

I am trying to read such input data in c++;

Input:

Hi, I am John. How are you?

I am

How are you

I want to store the first string line to s, second line string to subs1, third string line to subs2.

I tried using getline for each line, it would not work.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <climits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    string s, sub1, sub2;
    getline(cin, s);
    getline(cin, sub1);
    getline(cin, sub2);
```

How can I achieve that?

Also, what is the difference between:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <climits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string s = "", s1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        getline(cin, s1);
        s += s1;
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

and :

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <climits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string s = "", s1;
    while (getline(cin, s1)) {
        s += s1; 
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to provide `cin` to `getline` function if you are reading from file, you need to provide a stream to the file. Example of how to get one:

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream ifs ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);
getline(ifs, str);
```

The difference in those two code snippets is that you don't have to specify number of lines to read, with `while(getline)` it will read the file till it reaches the end of file.

Comment: Though, the one with the for loop, let's say n denotes to the number of lines, it doesn't read until the nth line. About the variables, isn't there any other better way to use getline to assign every line containing space to targeted variables?